# Using a tilde in a .bib file

Tags: bibtex, urls

We have a bibliographic entry which is like this:

```
@misc{entry,
    title={Some Title},
    year={2023},
    url="https://website.com/~something/something.pdf"
}
```

The problem is that the tilde ∼ does not render correctly when pasted into the URL box of a browser. It somehow becomes a non-standard tilde character. What can we do to render it normally?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Load package `xurl` in your preample ...

Comment: Loading xurl does not seem to fix the issue. (As an aside, I am the author of this question - apparently I forgot to log in. Can someone please merge it with my account?)

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue, could you edit into your question a small example of code that produces the error you have please?

Answer (score 4):

Adding the tilde as `$\sim$` with the URL in parenthesis `{}` might solve the issue:

```
@misc{entry,
    title={Some Title},
    year={2023},
    url={https://website.com/$\sim$something/something.pdf},
}
```